# jQuery select different links with different class for links

Tags: jquery

I have following code

```
      $("a[class!='mcatd,prev,next']").click(function () {
            $("#overlay").css("display", "block");

        })
```

html

```
  <div id="overlay">
    <span class="centerMe">Loading. Please wait...</span>
</div>
```

basically I need to change display property when links with classes get clicked except some classes. How can I achieve this. above code not working

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: @mplungjan this is all the code I have got

Comment: @Alex: I guess that would be your problem then.  Without any HTML, this code won't do anything.

Comment: You did not post anything with classes 'mcatd,prev,next' and you are now testing a string and not a classList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `not()` function here

```
$("a:not(.mcatd,.prev,.next)").click(function () {
    $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
})
```

Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.not()` method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against each element; the elements that don't match the selector will be included in the result.

You can find a detailed explanation [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/not/)